# What's the right way to shutdown Arch Linux through dbus interface?

Tags: arch-linux, shutdown, d-bus

I'm running `openbox` with Arch Linux, and looks like the old console kit interface has been long gone,

```
%> dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit was not provided by any .service files
```

So what's the interface to use now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Systemd manages dbus sessions in Arch. If you have an active `logind` session, then you can shutdown or reboot using systemd, without root privileges. See the [power management section of the systemd page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Power_management) on the Arch Wiki:

```
systemctl poweroff
```

If there are other active seats, you will be prompted for a password.

Comment: Just wondering, what is the difference between this and `shutdown`? I have always been using the `shutdown` command to shutdown my system, should I be using `systemd`?

Comment: @PlasmaPower See [this question and answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77029/why-are-reboot-shutdown-and-poweroff-symlinks-to-systemctl): I use `systemctl $command` because it encourages the habit of using systemd commands.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was looking for a question like that. I think I will be using `systemd` to shutdown my system, chrome was complaining about not being shutdown properly when I used `shutdown`. +1, I didn't know that you had to have a `logind` session.

Comment: @PlasmaPower Having an active login session is a very good idea: it will make a whole lot of things work as intended...